# Customize wp-admin form custom fields

Tags: jquery, wp-admin, forms

I would like to customize some form elements in my WP admin area: starting from this example (http://api.jquery.com/val/ the one with the select) what I would liko to do, is to update a  via a select field. In order to do so I started including this function:

```
function my_enqueue() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/admin.js' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

Inside "admin.js" I placed:

```
alert("It works!");
```

And it does work. But whenever I try to include anything related to jQuery nothing happens: the code is being included inside the page and I get no errors in Firebug. For example a script as simple as the one you can find at http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_keyup.asp

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
    $("input").css("background-color","pink");
});
```

Doesn't work. Nothing happens. So I wonder, what am i missing or doing wrong? Thansk a lot!

Comment: Do you have the code wrapped in document ready wrappers? Have you made sure to support "$"? What is the full code of admin.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is your problem if you are not getting any errors, but make sure you have your jQuery code within document ready wrappers and pass the $ in to make sure you can access it since Wordpress runs in no-conflict mode.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("input").keyup(function(){
        $("input").css("background-color","pink");
    });

});
```

It would also be good to declare jQuery as a dependency just to be safe.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/admin.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
```